# Is there a way to get email notifications when someone tweets?

Tags: twitter

I would like to know if there is any way in which I can get email notifications when only "specific" people tweet on Twitter.

Further, would it be possible to filter these alerts based on some hashtags or specific words that they use?

Comment: I am checking with http://ifttt.com/ but not sure if that would work. Are there any solutions geared for tackling only this?

Comment: ifttt has a trigger in the Twitter channel called "New tweet by specific user" - that seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @masterjo Yup. I think Ifft works just well for what I need. Wonderful to know ifft can accomplish so much and more. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @masterjo move the comment to an answer!

Comment: @masterjo the "New tweet by specific user" does not seem to be available anymore :(

Comment: "New tweet by specific user" has been restored, along with several other triggers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[IFTTT](http://www.ifttt.com) has a trigger in the Twitter channel, "New tweet by specific user", which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

[Zapier](https://zapier.com) has a trigger like that as well and provides the exact [recipe](https://zapier.com/app/editor/template/1306) you want for this purpose:

> If you’ve got a Twitter user that you want to keep an extra special eye on, Zapier can provide a big assist. Get an email when a specific Twitter user posts a new update. With our Twitter integration, anytime that user tweets, you'll get notified via email.

[Zapier's Twitter integration](https://zapier.com/apps/twitter/integrations), offered free at one point, now requires a paid plan.

Comment: There is no longer a Twitter channel for this kind of thing. This answer will no longer work: look to the other solutions in this thread.

Comment: @Fogest: I just checked on iftt.com and the channel as well as the specific are is still available. See here: https://ifttt.com/channel/twitter/triggers/28-new-tweet-by-a-specific-user

Comment: I remember it being gone before. They must have re added it then. Sweet.

Answer (score 6):

You could also try an RSS-to-email solution. You can get a user's tweets in RSS from:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=USERNAME
```

Or a hashtag search from:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=%23HASHTAG
```

Then an RSS-to-email service like http://www.feedmyinbox.com/. (Note: I've never used this—it was the first hit on a Google search.)

Comment: The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1

Answer (score 3):

I needed this too, and it was easy to solve using [Zapier](https://zapier.com).

I created an account, then set up a 'zap' using the trigger `Twitter → User Tweet` and connected my Twitter account. The nice thing is that this works on protected account tweets as well.

You can then send it to email, Pushover, or whatever else Zapier supports.

[Zapier's Twitter integration](https://zapier.com/apps/twitter/integrations) is now only available with a paid plan.

Answer (score 2):

I made it with this:

Tweets to RSS: http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=USER_NAME
Then go here: https://www.feedmyinbox.com/

And fill there RSS URL and your email..

Comment: It seems that twitrss.me is no longer active.

Answer (score 1):

This [IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/234075-new-tweet-by-specific-user-send-me-an-email) is specifically for getting an email message whenever a specific user tweets.

It's originally configured to send the @username and the tweet text, but you can customize it to contain other elements, such as a link to the tweet or the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

[Twilert](http://twilert.com) will do exactly what you want. You can be sent emails on a regular basis that search a specific Twitter account and filter based on hashtags or words.

Comment: Twilert appears to be no longer in operation.

Answer (score 0):

A way around this is  to set up a [Google Alerts](https://www.google.com/alerts) alert for the @name or the #hashtag you want to receive alerts for. There are sites but they cost money. [www.twilert.com](http://www.twilert.com/) is one, but I feel like this is a service that will be free in the next few years.

Answer (score 0):

I used this [telegram applet](https://ifttt.com/applets/461483p-twitter-search-hashtag-to-telegram) on IFTTT for this.

---

**Steps:**

- I created a bot from [Bot Father](https://telegram.me/botfather) by telling him to create a new bot: `/newbot`
- I sent a message to my new bot on telegram, then got the channel id by:

  `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"allowed_updates": ["message]"}' https://api.telegram.org/botYOUR_BOT_ID/getUpdates`
- Inside the returned json, I've got the "chat_id".
- Then I put a webhook into the IFTTT applet like this:

  `https://api.telegram.org/botYOUR_BOT_ID/sendMessage`
- I configured the payload inside the applet like this:

  `{"chat_id":"YOUR_CHAT_ID", "text":"{{UserName}} tweeted:\n\n{{Text}}\n\n{{LinkToTweet}}\n\n{{CreatedAt}}"}`

---

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My website https://www.MyTweetAlerts.com does this. There is a free trial for 30 days. 
This tool is founded on the idea that there should be a better way to search Twitter. It allows you to easily set up and deliver custom alerts to your inbox, saving you time and maximizing your efficiency on Twitter. With the ability to search based on a number of criteria including keywords, locations, urls, likes,and number of followers, think of it as Google Alerts for Twitter.

You can set up email notifications when someone is tweeting about some keywords and also only if it is from specific Twitter users.

One unique feature is that you can create emails alerts and get emails when someone tweets about some topics and the tweet has more than X likes or Y retweets or the Twitter user has more than X followers. Then you can spot Tweets that might go viral.

Answer (score -2):

If you ever want to get email messages when a person tweets:

1. Get the RSS feed link for the person's twitter stream:

   `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=USERNAME`

   (replace USERNAME with their actual twitter name and copy the link)
2. Blogtrottr will turn an RSS feed to email messages.  Go over to http://blogtrottr.com and paste link in to subscribe.